# Is there a way to aggregate/concat exports in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a sort of library file in some package with a bunch of exports like this:

```js
// conversation.ts

const hello = 'Hello';
const goodbye = 'Goodbye';

export {
  hello,
  goodbye,
};
```

And then lets say I have another library like this:

```js
// questions.ts

const howAreYou = 'how are you?';
const whereDoYouLive = 'where do you live?';

export {
    howAreYou,
    whereDoYouLive,
};
```

What I really want to do is to make `conversation.ts` *extend* the `questions.ts` library.

#### I would like to be able to do something like this:

```js
// conversation.ts

const hello = 'Hello';
const goodbye = 'Goodbye';

import * as questions from "./questions.ts";

export {
  hello,
  goodbye,
  // This is not possible, but I wish it was
  ...questions,
};
```

That way you could publish or import the `conversation` library and have the `questions` library *included*.

```js
import {
  hello,
  howAreYou,
} from "./conversation";
```

The closest I can think of this would be to either do

##### A. Import the other file with `* as`

```js
// conversation.ts

const hello = 'Hello';
const goodbye = 'Goodbye';

import * as questions from "./questions.ts";

export {
  hello,
  goodbye,
  questions,
};
```

##### or B. Import each export in the other file by hand

```js
// conversation.ts

const hello = 'Hello';
const goodbye = 'Goodbye';

import { howAreYou, whereDoYouLive } from "./questions.ts";

export {
  hello,
  goodbye,
  howAreYou,
  whereDoYouLive,
};
```

A. doesn't work because I want all the imports to be on the same level.

B. doesn't work because I will have a ton of imports and I'd rather not do them all by hand like that.

Is there any way to concat or spread export objects together in TypeScript?

(This is a bit of a strange question so let me stress that I'm just asking if it's **technically possible**, not what I should do instead, or how I should organize my code.)

**EDIT:** As per the answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73979460/8620945) this is possible [in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#syntax) and [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#re-exports) with `export * from "./questions`.

Comment: Seems to work in stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-1rfwnt?file=conversation.ts

Comment: @caTS Yes indeed it does. My mistake was using `import *` instead of `export *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have yet to consider exporting directly:

```
export * from "./questions.ts";
```

Comment: That would be great but that produces the error `'as' expected` (when using TypeScript at least)

Comment: @AdamD That's quite odd because it's listed as one of the options [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export). Maybe you copied it wrong or your TS version is severely outdated? Beats me.

Comment: Yes it works for JavaScript but not for TypeScript (just tried it with the latest `create-react-app` and TypeScript and it doesn't work)

Comment: @AdamD Do you mind editing the question and adding in the error you get and the versions of CRA and TS you are using?

Comment: It's also explicitly listed on the TS Handbook under [Reference / Modules / "Re-exports"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#re-exports).

Comment: @caTS Thanks so much you're right this does work, but for some reason the [original StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-c9mnfm?file=conversation.ts) I gave I posted on StackBlitz still doesn't work, but [this fork of it does work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-in9y3y?file=App.tsx).

Comment: @AdamD Your line 4 says `import *`; caTS has `export *`. [MDN docs on `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) confirm that `import *` is only allowed when followed by `as`; you cannot `import` all identifiers into the current file, even though you can re-export them without importing them. (I think the reasoning is that an unrestricted import would pollute the namespace.)

Comment: @JeffBowman oh yes thank you! I didn't see that. It all makes sense now. StackOverflow is amazing and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `export default`?

```
export default {
  hello,
  goodbye,
  ...questions,
};
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind: it would totally change how you would import things.

Comment: Wouldn't that also break tree-shaking? Like I would have to `import conversation from "./conversation"` and that would give me the whole library.

Comment: @AdamD - yeah, I initially thought that you can also destructure the default export. Seems like you can't, so probably not a good option anyway